# Azure Germany: Call to changePassword not working

Tags: azure, graph, passwords

We are currently hosting two similar webapps in Azure, one inside the international cloud, one inside the german one. We are using the Graph-API to change a user's initial password. This works for the international version but fails when trying the same for the german one. See the method below, which shows the code for the german app. The international version obviously has other ids, keys and URLs, but uses the same logic.

Debugging the code, I do get a token and I can use the token for the POST method. This is the Response (after calling client.PostAsync):

> Id = 42, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "StatusCode: 500,
>    ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, 
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
>   Headers:\r\n{\r\n
>   ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: 5gghBUs/j/tLLA4x7srNaYCSuNTD7zpqDaqBOfa330o=\r\n
>   request-id: 2258910e-3b51-47a7-bd81-90eb46a31cb0\r\n
>   client-request-id: {myClientId}\r\n
>   }" (...)

I have checked every id, key and Url tenfold. What am I missing? (Client-Id, username etc are anonymized)

```
private async static Task<string> ChangePasswordDE()
    {
        try
        {

            string clientId = "{myClientID }";
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.de/{TenantID}/";

            string userName = "Name@Tenant.onmicrosoft.de";
            string oldPassword = "thisIsOld1234";
            string newPassword = "thisIsNew5678";


            var ctx = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
            var pwCred = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, oldPassword);
            var result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.cloudapi.de/", clientId, pwCred).Result;

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);


            var requestUri = "https://graph.cloudapi.de/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6";

            object newPwd = new { currentPassword = oldPassword, newPassword = newPassword };

            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPwd);
            Uri uri = new Uri(requestUri);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            Console.WriteLine("Post Async");
            var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

            ctx.TokenCache.Clear();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worked!");
                return "OK";

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
                Console.WriteLine("Did not work!");
                return "Error";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been in contact with Microsoft. Azure Germany does implement the Graph API, but, as of March 1st 2017, not all functions are fully working yet. ChangePassword used in the way above is one of them.